# Create dynamic JSON with sql output

Tags: javascript, json

I try to create a dynamic JSON whith data returned from my database :
What I want to have :

```
var myJSON = {  
              "value" : [ { 
"icon_name": "value", 
"factor_name": "value", 
"number": "value", 
"priority": "value" 
}, 
{ 
"icon_name": "value", 
"factor_name": "value", 
"number": "value", 
"priority": "value" 
} ],
                  "value" : [ { 
"icon_name": "value", 
"factor_name": "value", 
"number": "value", 
"priority": "value" 
}, 
{ 
"icon_name": "value", 
"factor_name": "value", 
"number": "value", 
"priority": "value"  
} ],
...
  };
```

Each "value" is dynamic and depend of my sql response. My sql response looks like this.

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    row_names: 587,
    icon_name: 'small_event',
    factor_name: 'Petit évènement',
    number: 10,
    priority: 1 },
  RowDataPacket {
    row_names: 587,
    icon_name: 'cold',
    factor_name: 'Température basse',
    number: 10,
    priority: 7 },
  RowDataPacket {
    row_names: 587,
    icon_name: 'rain',
    factor_name: 'Pluie',
    number: 10,
    priority: 12 },
  RowDataPacket {
    row_names: 588,
    icon_name: 'small_event',
    factor_name: 'Petit évènement',
    number: 10,
    priority: 1 },
  RowDataPacket {
    row_names: 588,
    icon_name: 'cold',
    factor_name: 'Température basse',
    number: 10,
    priority: 7 }]
```

There are several values (icon_name, factor_name, ...) for one row_names. I want to regroup all these values for each unique row_names.

Here my code (rows[3] is my sql output):

```
var result = []
var r_names = "";
var j = 0;
var id = "";

for(i = 0; i < rows[3].length; i++) {
  if(r_names != rows[3][i].row_names) {
    j = 0;
    id = ''+rows[3][i].row_names;
    result[id] = [];

    r_names = rows[3][i].row_names
  }
  result[id].push({});
  result[id][j]["icon_name"] = rows[3][i].icon_name,
  result[id][j]["factor_name"] = rows[3][i].factor_name,
  result[id][j]["number"] = rows[3][i].number,
  result[id][j]["priority"] = rows[3][i].priority
  j++;
}
```

Here my result :

```
 ...
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  [ { icon_name: 'small_event',
      factor_name: 'Petit évènement',
      number: 10,
      priority: 1 },
    { icon_name: 'temperate',
      factor_name: 'Température modéré',
      number: 10,
      priority: 7 },
    { icon_name: 'rain',
      factor_name: 'Pluie',
      number: 10,
      priority: 12 } ],
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
...
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
  [ { icon_name: 'small_event',
      factor_name: 'Petit évènement',
      number: 10,
      priority: 1 },
    { icon_name: 'temperate',
      factor_name: 'Température modéré',
      number: 10,
      priority: 7 },
    { icon_name: 'rain',
      factor_name: 'Pluie',
      number: 10,
      priority: 12 } ] ]
```

I have no idea why I have so much ','. I didn't succeed to find my error.
Have you an idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, you take value of `row_names` as index for the array and that is at start `587`. With that index, you generate a sparse array.

```
id = ''+rows[3][i].row_names;
result[id] = [];
```

To prevent this, you could use an object, then you could use `row_names`'s value as key for the result.

```
var result = {};
```

Comment: In fact i tried to convert my row_names as a string to avoid errors, but it didn't works. I'm sorry but I'm not sure to totally understand your solution. How can I use object here. It will change nothing no ?

Comment: change `var result = []` to `var result = {}`